# HAL_RCC_OscConfig returns HAL_TIMEOUT

Tags: stm32f4, hal, stm32cubemx

I'm trying to configure a development board with **STM32F411CEU6**.
This board have two crystals (25Mhz and 32,768KHz).
I'm trying to compile code generated from **CubeMX** with different configurations, but **HAL_RCC_OscConfig** returns always **HAL_TIMEOUT**.
I tried to:

- stretch the timeout of 1000ms
- lower the clock from 100Mhz to 96, 72 and 50MHz.
- disable the LSE crystal

but is everything useless.

This is the **SystemClock_Config** function:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 25;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 200;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

Comment: Debug into the call to `HAL_RCC_OscConfig`. Which bit specifically is timing out?

Comment: During HSE initialization, this is the incriminated code:

while(__HAL_RCC_GET_FLAG(RCC_FLAG_HSERDY) != RESET)
{
          if((HAL_GetTick() - tickstart ) > HSE_TIMEOUT_VALUE)
          {
                 return HAL_TIMEOUT;
          }
}

Comment: Check the reference manual for what that flag means, but from memory maybe the crystal isn't starting? Is this a PCB you've designed in-house?

Comment: The board was purchased online and I discovered that the HSE oscillator is defective :(

Comment: Ah, that would explain it!

Comment: @Stefano, thanks for your comment. I've a similar board (stm32f411e-disc) with the same defective crystal (must be from the same batch) and didn't think of trying the internal oscillator until I saw your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this development board (and others) `HAL_Timeout` in `HAL_RCC_OscConfig` would be caused if HSE is selected as the clock source in the `Clock Configuration` tab of the CubeIDE Configuration Tool (CubeMX) and then mis-configuring HSE clock mode in RCC settings of the tool.

Check the following in the config tool (double-click `<projectname>.ioc` in IDE Project Explorer window to launch the tool). Under `Pinout & Configuration` tab select `Categories > System Core > RCC` then check that `Crystal/Ceramic Resonator` is selected in the `High Speed Clock (HSE)` dropdown of the RCC Mode window. The other two options `Disable` and `BYPASS Clock Source` would cause the HSE clock source to not select the on-board crystal and hence cause the HAL timeout.

PS: `BYPASS Clock Source` would be the option to choose if you are supplying your own clock into the `RCC_OSC_IN` pin of the MCU.

Comment: 1. Elaborate the question and use proper formatting for the code
2. Share your initial research and effort to fix the issue, and if anything worked or not?